# Parsing string between multi-level brackets to node

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking for a way (algorithm or java code) to parse string with multi level brackets like this:

```
(Level 1
    (Level 1.1
        (Level 1.1.1)
        (Level 1.1.2)
        (Level 1.1.3)
    )
    (Level 1.2
        (Level 1.2.1)
        (Level 1.2.2)
        (Level 1.2.3)
    )
)
```

to node with structure:
[image: node structure]

I've tried to use `text.substring(text.indexOf('(') + 1 , text.lastIndexOf(')') - 1)` in recursive method, but it doesn't work properly in case when you have few brackets in the same level.

Comment: Use should use data structure like stack for this problem

Comment: @venkat that's a bit reductive. A stack can be used to count parentheses and to balance-check them, but in the end this is structured like a tree.

Comment: read about recursive descent parsing, although simpler methods will work as well in this case.

Comment: This data you have, do you creating it yourself? If yes I suggest to use JSON or XML formats instead, and then parsing wouldn be a problem. Jackson Object Mapper for example.

Comment: @federico - Yes, we can use suitable data structure, but we cannot eliminate stack

Comment: would share some sample input and output? which could help to understand

Comment: if you really like to do like this, then use regular expression.

Comment: This is a good candidate for YAML

Comment: @AndyNope using regular expressions for something that is not a regular language is doomed to fail.

Comment: @Henry It may work if we don't care about the lines: (Level 1 (Level 1.1 (Level 1.1.1) (Level 1.1.2) (Level 1.1.3) ) (Level 1.2 (Level 1.2.1) (Level 1.2.2) (Level 1.2.3) ) )

Comment: `data = data.replaceAll("\n", "");` to put all on the same level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exercise recursion check this:

```
public class Grouping {


    private static final String data = "(Level 1 \n" +
            "    (Level 1.1\n" +
            "        (Level 1.1.1)\n" +
            "        (Level 1.1.2)\n" +
            "        (Level 1.1.3)\n" +
            "    )\n" +
            "    (Level 1.2\n" +
            "        (Level 1.2.1)\n" +
            "        (Level 1.2.2)\n" +
            "        (Level 1.2.3)\n" +
            "    )\n" +
            ")";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = data.replaceAll("\n", "").trim();
        System.out.println(s);
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        Data data = createData(chars);
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    private static Data createData(char[] chars) {
        Data result = new Data();
        for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
            result.length++;
            if (chars[i] == ')') {
                return result;
            }
            if (chars[i] == '(') {
                Data data = createData(Arrays.copyOfRange(chars, i, chars.length));
                i += data.length;
                result.length += data.length;
                result.nested.add(data);
            } else result.name.append(chars[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Data {
    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    int length = 0;
    List<Data> nested = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

if you trying to make something usefull, better stick to already invented data structures like json, xml etc, and tools sharpened by them. Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are trying to accomplish. I don't see anything wrong with the structure contained within the string other than the fact that its only usefulness is pretty much purely visual.

What your example string is showing is a single string depiction of a Ascending Hierarchical Tree. Visually it definitely gets the job done but its useful practicality leaves much to be desired. From what I gather you want to maintain the Tree structure but modify the data structure which makes up this Tree from a single string to something more useful where each Parent and or Child of the Tree can be easily (or more easily) accessed for other purposes than perhaps a visual Tree.

This can be done but first you need to take a close look at how the initial string makes up the Tree. A String is a single line of data, what separates the string components (substrings) into individual lines in the display of that string are line-break characters within the string (such as "\n"). Here is an example:

```
String treeString = "(Level 1\n"
                  + "    (Level 1.1\n"
                  + "        (Level 1.1.1)\n"
                  + "        (Level 1.1.2\n"
                  + "            (Level 1.1.2.1)\n"
                  + "            (Level 1.1.2.2)\n"
                  + "            (Level 1.1.2.3)\n"
                  + "            (Level 1.1.2.4)\n"
                  + "        )\n"
                  + "        (Level 1.1.3)\n"
                  + "    )\n"
                  + "    (Level 1.2\n"
                  + "        (Level 1.2.1)\n"
                  + "        (Level 1.2.2)\n"
                  + "        (Level 1.2.3)\n"
                  + "    )\n"
                  + "    (Level 1.3)\n"
                  + "    (Level 1.4)\n"
                  + ")\n"
                  + "(Level 2\n"
                  + "    (Level 2.1)\n"
                  + "    (Level 2.2\n"
                  + "        (Level 2.2.1)\n"
                  + "    )\n"
                  + "    (Level 2.3)\n"
                  + "    (Level 2.4\n"
                  + "        (Level 2.4.1)\n"
                  + "        (Level 2.4.2)\n"
                  + "    )\n"
                  + ")";
```

This is a somewhat more complex String Tree example than what you provided and it will be the string we'll use to restructure the data within the string. In the above code you can see the line-break characters (**\n**) at the end of each substring within the main string. When this string is displayed within a Console Window for example it would look something like this:

```
(Level 1
    (Level 1.1
        (Level 1.1.1)
        (Level 1.1.2
            (Level 1.1.2.1)
            (Level 1.1.2.2)
            (Level 1.1.2.3)
            (Level 1.1.2.4)
        )
        (Level 1.1.3)
    )
    (Level 1.2
        (Level 1.2.1)
        (Level 1.2.2)
        (Level 1.2.3)
    )
    (Level 1.3)
    (Level 1.4)
)
(Level 2
    (Level 2.1)
    (Level 2.2
        (Level 2.2.1)
    )
    (Level 2.3)
    (Level 2.4
        (Level 2.4.1)
        (Level 2.4.2)
    )
)
```

Again, the usefulness of this string is pretty much purely visual and really doesn't make it all that easy to pull specific data from it. In the above Tree you can clearly see both Parent and Children nodes. A Parent node always contains a single open parentheses [ **(** ] and a Child node always contains both open and close parentheses [ **( )** ]. A Child can also be a Parent **if** that Child has Children. You can see this as the nodes nest (branches) gets deeper. The end of any particular Parent Branch is always denoted by a ***single*** Closing parenthesis [ **)** ].

With the above information we can develop a different data structure. A structure where we can even apply that data to fill a Swing **JTree**. The data structure we will convert our String to is a **Nodes Path** structure where each Tree Node is stored as a String in the similar format of a file path, for example:

```
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.2/Level 1.1.2.1
```

Here, ***Level 1.1.2.1*** is the Child to the Parent ***Level 1.1.2*** and Parent ***Level 1.1.2*** is the Child to Parent ***Level 1.1*** and Parent ***Level 1.1*** is the Child to Parent ***Level 1***.

To start with we need to separate all the Tree data components (Parents and Children) from the String itself. To do this we split the string into a Single Dimensional String Array using the String#split() method. We split the Tree String based on the Line-Break character:

```
String[] nodes = treeString.split("\n");
```

Now we need to get rid of all those dead indent whitespaces that will be attached to a great many of the String Array elements:

```
// Trim off whitespaces on all elements
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i] = nodes[i].trim();
}
```

What you should end up with is a String Array that looks like this:

```
[(Level 1, (Level 1.1, (Level 1.1.1), (Level 1.1.2, (Level 1.1.2.1), (Level 1.1.2.2), 
(Level 1.1.2.3), (Level 1.1.2.4), ), (Level 1.1.3), ), (Level 1.2, (Level 1.2.1), (Level 1.2.2), 
(Level 1.2.3), ), (Level 1.3), (Level 1.4), ), (Level 2, (Level 2.1), (Level 2.2, (Level 2.2.1), ), 
(Level 2.3), (Level 2.4, (Level 2.4.1), (Level 2.4.2), ), )]
```

To create the desired Node Paths we will utilize the [Stack Class](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/stack.html). We'll create a method named **getNodePathsFromStringTree()** to which we will pass the above Tree String. The code above is incorporated within the method. This method will return a Java List Interface of String Type containing all the Node Paths to make the Tree:

```
public List<String> getNodePathsFromStringTree(String treeString) {
    // Convert treeString to a 1D String Array
    String[] nodes = treeString.split("\n");
    // Trim off whitespaces from all elements (we don't want them).
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i] = nodes[i].trim();
    }

    List<String> nodePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].startsWith("(") && !nodes[i].endsWith(")")) {
            stack.push(nodes[i].substring(1));
        }
        else if (nodes[i].startsWith("(") && nodes[i].endsWith(")")) {
            stack.push(nodes[i].substring(1, (nodes[i].length() - 1)));
            String nodePath = "";
            Iterator<String> iterator = stack.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String value = iterator.next();
                nodePath += nodePath.equals("") ? value : "/" + value;
            }
            stack.pop();
            nodePaths.add(nodePath);
        }
        else if (nodes[i].equals(")")) {
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    return nodePaths;
}
```

To use the above method you would do something like:

```
List<String> nodePaths = getNodePathsFromStringTree(treeString);
```

By passing the above Tree String to the above **getNodePathsFromStringTree()** method you will be returned a List of Node Paths that look like:

```
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.1
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.2/Level 1.1.2.1
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.2/Level 1.1.2.2
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.2/Level 1.1.2.3
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.2/Level 1.1.2.4
Level 1/Level 1.1/Level 1.1.3
Level 1/Level 1.2/Level 1.2.1
Level 1/Level 1.2/Level 1.2.2
Level 1/Level 1.2/Level 1.2.3
Level 1/Level 1.3
Level 1/Level 1.4
Level 2/Level 2.1
Level 2/Level 2.2/Level 2.2.1
Level 2/Level 2.3
Level 2/Level 2.4/Level 2.4.1
Level 2/Level 2.4/Level 2.4.2
```

With the above data structure you can clearly see the Tree Structure as to exactly where the Parent and Child formations exist. Think of the Paths as Folders, Sub-Folders, and Files. This data structure can now be used to fill a JTree. In reality, you can create a Tree with a single string and create a JTree based on the concept within that String.

If you would like a simple method to fill a JTree based on a supplied List of Node Paths then by all means let me know and I will supply one.